# linIt function in Octave

Tags: matlab, function, octave

I try to convert these [matlab scripts](https://github.com/s-gupta/nyu-hooks) to octave. However in getGroundTruthBoxes.m, it has following code:

```
freq = cell2mat(accumarray(inst(inst>0), segm(inst>0), [], @(x){linIt(histc(x,1:numClass))'}, {zeros(1,numClass)}$
```

When i try to run with octave, it gives " linIt undefined" error. I googled "linIt" functions , but i can not reach any information about linIt. Can you give information about this "linIt" function?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a MATLAB function, it's likely something missing (or that you've missed) in the linked source code.

Comment: that is _one_ ugly one-liner ... maybe it was from a codegolf challenge ...

Answer (score 1):

The user s-gupta whose repository you're using seems to have another repository called utils, where he defines this function https://github.com/s-gupta/utils/blob/master/matlab/linIt.m

Essentially it seems to be a tiny helper function that converts an array to its linearly indexed column-vector, i.e.

```
function a = linIt(A)
  a = A(:);
end
```